# Computer playing sound from a TV commercial. How does this happen

Tags: macos

This just started happening tonight on my iMac running High Sierra. About every 15 or 20 minutes my computer plays the sound track, or part of the soundtrack, from a common TV commercial. This Capitol One commercial is probably used on many websites but I don't know that for sure. I don't know how or why this is happening but I'd like to turn it off or stop it some way. I've had this happen when I have a web page open and a commercial is played but I have closed all browser windows and quit all browsers. But that didn't stop it. I don't see anything happening on my computer when the sound starts playing. I ran Malwarebytes but it said my computer is clean. How does a sound play without an application? Can someone tell me how to find what is going on?

Comment: ...Well, *something* must be running in the background. If you reboot with "reopen windows when logging back in" *unchecked*, and don't open any programs once the computer has turned back on, does the sound still play after 20 minutes?

Answer (score 2):

I opened activity monitor and checked it whenever the sound started playing. Dashboard started using a lot of computer resources when this occurred. I inadvertently copied something to the dashboard that would play these soundtracks. I deleted 2 files there that I knew nothing about and that solved my problem.

Comment: Nice work troubleshooting through Activity Monitor. I would not have thought of the Dashboard.